# Uso de funciones con ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, funciones

Buenos días amigos de este foro.

Tengo un problema, al ejecutar una instrucción js desde una función que se ejecuta con el `onreadystatechange` del ajax, cuyo fin es actualizar los datos de un formulario, algunas instrucciones no se ejecutan. Al principio pensé que se trataba de un error de sintaxis, sin embargo, la misma instrucción sí se ejecuta desde la consola del navegador. Esto me ha llevado a pensar que existen algunas limitaciones para las instrucciones que pueden usarse desde una función en ajax, en tiempo de ejecución.

Si alguien sabe algo al respecto, le agradezco la ayuda.
A continuación copio el código:

```js
    xact.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xact.readyState == 4 && xact.status == 200){
            actDatos =xact.responseText;
            actDatos = JSON.parse(actDatos);
            buscarProvinciaEd(actDatos[0].pais);
            buscarMunicipioEd(actDatos[0].estado);
            candNombre.value = actDatos[0].nombre;
            candDocIde.value = actDatos[0].docidentidad;
            candFnac.value   = actDatos[0].nacimiento;
            candDirecc.value = actDatos[0].direccion;
            candTelef.value  = actDatos[0].telefono;
            candMail.value   = actDatos[0].email;
            candAspSa.value  = actDatos[0].salariopref;
            candObjet.value  = actDatos[0].objetivo;
            //$("#cSexo option[value="+ actDatos[0].sexo +"]").attr("selected",true);
            $("#cprofArea option[value="+ actDatos[0].rama +"]").attr("selected",true);
            $("#cPais option[value="+ actDatos[0].pais +"]").attr("selected",true);
            $("#cEstado option[value="+ actDatos[0].estado +"]").attr("selected",true);
            $("#cMunicipio option[value="+ actDatos[0].municipio +"]").attr("selected",true);
            candSexo.value   = actDatos[0].sexo;
            //candAreaP.value  = actDatos[0].rama;
            //candPais.value   = actDatos[0].pais;
            //candEstado.value = actDatos[0].estado;
            //candMunici.value = actDatos[0].municipio;
        }
```

Comment: Por favor sé más específico con tu pregunta, no se entiende que problema tienes y el código que pones no dice mucho al estar incompleto. Se muestra algún error en consola?

Comment: Asegúrate que no estas haciendo una llamada Sincrona. `onreadystatechange` es sólo para llamadas asíncronas. En lugar de `xact.readyState == 4`, sería más claro si usas `xact.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE` Hay alguna razón de porque no usas `onload` ? Posiblemente ya has visto esto, pero aquí hay algunos ejemplos de como hacer las llamadas de forma síncronas y asíncronas: [Solicitudes síncronas y asíncronas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests)

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte.
La llamada es asíncrona, el problema lo tengo con la asignación de valores a los elementos cPais, cEstado, cMunicipio, el navegador no devuelve ningún error, simplemente no hace la asignación del valor. Llama la atención que el el caso de la primera asignación que hago con jquery, al elemento con id cprofArea si se ejecuta correctamente, como puedes ver la sintaxis utilizada para ambos casos es exactamente igual, sin embargo se ejecuta correctamente para el primer caso y no se ejecuta para los siguientes.

Comment: Las lineas comentadas, fueron formas alternativas de solución que ya probé.

Comment: El navegador no devuelve ningún error. El problema lo tengo con la asignación de valores a los elementos cPais, cEstado y cMunicipio, los cuales cargan correctamente sus valores con otra llamada ajax, al verificar en el navegador el elemento, tiene todas sus options, sólo que la asignación de valor que hago con el comando jquery no se realiza, es decir no preselecciona nada.

Comment: Sin embargo utilizo el mismo procedimiento con el elemento cSexo y se realiza correctamente, pero en ese caso los valores del select se cargan en el código, pero en el caso del elemento cprofArea, cuyos valores si se cargan mediante otra llamada ajax, la selección que hago con el comando jquery funciona perfectamente, esto es lo que hace extraño que para los otros tres elementos no funcione.

Comment: Ok, vamos por partes. 1) Ya te aseguraste que los datos que estas recibiendo, vienen con los nombres que tu esperas? (imprimiendo en la consola o examinando la respuesta con las herramientas del navegador)

Comment: 2) Ya que no muestras el resto del codigo, asumo que el problema no es con Ajax, sino con las lineas que mencionas. Supongo que estas tratando de seleccionar opciones de varios Select? De ser así, debes usar prop() en lugar de attr(). Además, los valores que quieres, incluyen los '+'? Tal vez si editas tu pregunta para agregar un poco más de tu código.